# ¿Por qué la función no funciona correctamente si los parámetros los lee por teclado? c++

Tags: c++, funciones, variables, parametros

Estoy desarrollando las funciones de un árbol binario en c++ y me ha surgido un problema en la función que realiza el insert: Si los parámetros los recibe de unas variables o se los pongo con comillas directamente cuando llamo a la función, todo bien. Pero si en lugar de eso leo por teclado unas variables y las introduzco como parámetros a la función entonces no funciona correctamente.

Más concretamente, si se le introducen los parámetros de la función por teclado, la función insertar detecta que la clave a introducir en el sistema ya  figura en el y por tanto no se puede introducir de nuevo(aunque en realidad no es así):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

/*******************************************************************************
Declaración del tipo Arbol como una estructura que contendrá un puntero llamado
raíz que apuntará a una estructura denominada nodoA
nodoA será una estructura que estructura que contendrá 3 clavees: la clave (que
sirve para ordenar los elementos dentro del árbol, izq que será un puntero a su
subárbol izquierdo y der que será un puntero a su subárbol derecho. Faltarían
los datos que contienen la información del nodo.
*******************************************************************************/
typedef struct nodoA
{
    char *clave;
    char    *marca;
    char    *modelo;
    char    *tipo;
    int     potencia;
    struct nodoA *izq,*der;
}*nodoarbol;

typedef struct Tree
{
    struct nodoA *raiz;
}*arbol;

/*******************************************************************************
Función que sirve para crear un árbol binario vacío. El nodo raíz contendrá
como clave inicial el valor -1 pero se considera que está vacío.
*******************************************************************************/
arbol CrearArbol()
{
    arbol ar= new struct Tree;
    ar->raiz = new struct nodoA;
    ar->raiz->izq = ar->raiz->der = NULL;
    ar->raiz->clave = "-1";
    return(ar);
}
/*******************************************************************************
Función que sirve para determinar si un árbol está vacío, es decir, si su
nodo raíz contiene la clave -1.
*******************************************************************************/
bool ArbolVacio(arbol ar)
{
    if (ar->raiz->clave =="-1") return(true);
    else return(false);
}
/*******************************************************************************
Función que determina si un valor para determinar si un valor clave existe en
el árbol.
*******************************************************************************/
bool BusquedaclaveArbol(nodoarbol nodo,char *laclave)
{
    if (nodo == NULL) return(false);
    else
    {
        if (nodo->clave ==laclave) return(true);
        else
        {
            if (nodo->clave < laclave) return(BusquedaclaveArbol(nodo->der,laclave));
            else return(BusquedaclaveArbol(nodo->izq,laclave));
        };
    };
}
/*******************************************************************************
Función que inserta una clave en el árbol si ésta no existe en él.
*******************************************************************************/
void InsertarclaveArbol(arbol ar,char *laclave, char *lamarca, char *elmodelo, char *eltipo, int lapotencia)
{
    struct nodoA *nodo_padre,*nodo_aux;
    nodo_padre = new struct nodoA;
    nodo_aux = new struct nodoA;
    nodo_padre = NULL;
    nodo_aux = ar->raiz;
    cout << "Raiz: " << nodo_aux << endl;
    cout << "Clave de la raiz: " << nodo_aux->clave << endl;
    cout << "Clave a insertar: " << laclave << endl;

    if (ArbolVacio(ar))
    {
        nodo_aux->clave = laclave;
        nodo_aux->marca = lamarca;
        nodo_aux->modelo = elmodelo;
        nodo_aux->tipo = eltipo;
        nodo_aux->potencia = lapotencia;
        return;
        //EN EL CASO DE QUE EL ARBOL ESTE VACIO SE ASIGNA LA CLAVE AL NODO RAIZ
    }

    while ((nodo_aux!=NULL) && (nodo_aux->clave!=laclave))
    {
        nodo_padre = nodo_aux; //RECORRER HASTA POSICIONARSE DONDE INSERTAR
        if( laclave < nodo_aux->clave) nodo_aux = nodo_aux->izq;
        else nodo_aux = nodo_aux->der;
    }

/* Si SE HA ENCONTRADO EL ELEMENTO, NO SE PUEDE INSERTAR */
    if (nodo_aux!=NULL)
    {
        cout << laclave << " NO SE PUEDE INSERTAR PUES YA EXISTE" << endl;
        return;
    };

    if(laclave < nodo_padre->clave)
    {
        /* SI LA CLAVE A INSERTAR ES MENOR QUE LA QUE CONTIENE EL NODO PADRE
        SE INSERTA EN EL SUBARBOL IZQUIERDO */
        struct nodoA *nodo;
        nodo = new struct nodoA;
        nodo_padre->izq = nodo;
        nodo->clave = laclave;
        nodo->marca = lamarca;
        nodo->modelo = elmodelo;
        nodo->tipo = eltipo;
        nodo->potencia = lapotencia;

        nodo->izq = nodo->der = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        /* SI LA CLAVE A INSERTAR ES MAYOR QUE LA QUE CONTIENE EL NODO PADRE
        SE INSERTA EN EL SUBARBOL DERECHO */
        struct nodoA *nodo;
        nodo = new struct nodoA;
        nodo_padre->der = nodo;
        nodo->clave = laclave;
        nodo->marca = lamarca;
        nodo->modelo = elmodelo;
        nodo->tipo = eltipo;
        nodo->potencia = lapotencia;
        nodo->izq = nodo->der = NULL;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    arbol elarbol1;
    elarbol1 = CrearArbol();

    if (ArbolVacio(elarbol1)) cout << "EL ARBOL ESTA VACIO" << endl;
    else cout << "EL ARBOL NO ESTA VACIO" << endl;

    char matricula[8] = "1111LLL";
    char modelo[10]= "modelo";
    char marca[10]= "marca";
    char tipo[10] = "tipo";
    int potencia = 500;

    char propmatricula[8];
    char propmodelo[10];
    char propmarca[10];
    char proptipo[10];
    int proppotencia;

    InsertarclaveArbol(elarbol1,(char *)"0000LLL",(char *)"Marca",(char *)"Modelo",(char *)"T",500);
    InsertarclaveArbol(elarbol1,matricula,marca,modelo,tipo,potencia);
    InsertarclaveArbol(elarbol1,(char *)"2222LLL",(char *)"Marca",(char *)"Modelo",(char *)"T",500);
    InsertarclaveArbol(elarbol1,(char *)"3333LLL",(char *)"Marca",(char *)"Modelo",(char *)"T",500);
    cout << "Matricula" << endl << "Opcion: ";
    cin >> propmatricula;
    strcpy(matricula, propmatricula);
    cout << "modelo" << endl << "Opcion: ";
    cin >> propmodelo;
    strcpy(modelo,propmodelo);
    cout << "marca" << endl << "Opcion: ";
    cin >> propmarca;
    strcpy(marca,propmarca);
    cout << "tipo" << endl << "Opcion: ";
    cin >> proptipo;
    strcpy(tipo,proptipo);
    cout << "potencia" << endl << "Opcion: ";
    cin >> potencia;

    InsertarclaveArbol(elarbol1,matricula,marca,modelo,tipo,potencia);
    InsertarclaveArbol(elarbol1,(char *)"5555LLL",(char *)"Marca",(char *)"Modelo",(char *)"T",500);
    InsertarclaveArbol(elarbol1,(char *)"6666LLL",(char *)"Marca",(char *)"Modelo",(char *)"T",500);
    InsertarclaveArbol(elarbol1,(char *)"7777LLL",(char *)"Marca",(char *)"Modelo",(char *)"T",500);
    InsertarclaveArbol(elarbol1,(char *)"8888LLL",(char *)"Marca",(char *)"Modelo",(char *)"T",500);

    if (ArbolVacio(elarbol1)) cout << "EL ARBOL ESTA VACIO" << endl;
    else cout << "EL ARBOL NO ESTA VACIO" << endl;

    char num[7];
    cout << "Matricula a buscar: ";
    cin >> num;
    if (BusquedaclaveArbol(elarbol1->raiz,num))
    cout << "EL clave " << num << " EXISTE EN EL ARBOL" << endl;
    else
    cout << "EL clave " << num << " NO EXISTE EN EL ARBOL" << endl;

    cout << "Matricula a buscar: ";
    cin >> num;
    if (BusquedaclaveArbol(elarbol1->raiz,num))
    cout << "EL clave " << num << " EXISTE EN EL ARBOL" << endl;
    else
    cout << "EL clave " << num << " NO EXISTE EN EL ARBOL" << endl;

    cout << "desea salir?" << endl;
    int decision;
    cin >> decision;
    if(decision == 1){
        system("PAUSE");    
    }

}
```

Comment: Los valores de los parámetros no tienen que ser por referencia con &?

Comment: Como? mi idea es que el usuario introduzca por teclado los datos del vehículo que quiera añadir al árbol

Comment: La función `InsertarclaveArbol` recibe como parámetros los punteros. Según la documentación de C++ debería ser (Int& laClave).

Comment: Gracias por su aclaración!! Lo único que al hacer eso me genera un fallo de compilación: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*'[-fpermissive]

Comment: Por favor, intenta proporcionar un [mcve]. Si tu problema está en `InsertarClaveArbol( )` ... ¿ Para que muestras el resto del código ?. Deberías pasarte por [el centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para saber como funciona el sitio. En concreto, deberías consultar [¿ Como elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nada, al final he cambiado el tipo de valor de char a string y me funciona perfecto:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

/*******************************************************************************
Declaración del tipo Arbol como una estructura que contendrá un puntero llamado
raíz que apuntará a una estructura denominada nodoA
nodoA será una estructura que estructura que contendrá 3 clavees: la clave (que
sirve para ordenar los elementos dentro del árbol, izq que será un puntero a su
subárbol izquierdo y der que será un puntero a su subárbol derecho. Faltarían
los datos que contienen la información del nodo.
*******************************************************************************/
typedef struct nodoA
{
    string clave;
    string  marca;
    string  modelo;
    string  tipo;
    int     potencia;
    struct nodoA *izq,*der;
}*nodoarbol;

typedef struct Tree
{
    struct nodoA *raiz;
}*arbol;

/*******************************************************************************
Función que sirve para crear un árbol binario vacío. El nodo raíz contendrá
como clave inicial el valor -1 pero se considera que está vacío.
*******************************************************************************/
arbol CrearArbol()
{
    arbol ar= new struct Tree;
    ar->raiz = new struct nodoA;
    ar->raiz->izq = ar->raiz->der = NULL;
    ar->raiz->clave = "-1";
    return(ar);
}
/*******************************************************************************
Función que sirve para determinar si un árbol está vacío, es decir, si su
nodo raíz contiene la clave -1.
*******************************************************************************/
bool ArbolVacio(arbol ar)
{
    if (ar->raiz->clave =="-1") return(true);
    else return(false);
}
/*******************************************************************************
Función que determina si un valor para determinar si un valor clave existe en
el árbol.
*******************************************************************************/
bool BusquedaclaveArbol(nodoarbol nodo,string laclave)
{
    if (nodo == NULL) return(false);
    else
    {
        if (nodo->clave ==laclave) return(true);
        else
        {
            if (nodo->clave < laclave) return(BusquedaclaveArbol(nodo->der,laclave));
            else return(BusquedaclaveArbol(nodo->izq,laclave));
        };
    };
}
/*******************************************************************************
Función que inserta una clave en el árbol si ésta no existe en él.
*******************************************************************************/
void InsertarclaveArbol(arbol ar,string laclave, string lamarca, string elmodelo, string eltipo, int lapotencia)
{
    struct nodoA *nodo_padre,*nodo_aux;
    nodo_padre = new struct nodoA;
    nodo_aux = new struct nodoA;
    nodo_padre = NULL;
    nodo_aux = ar->raiz;
    cout << "Raiz: " << nodo_aux << endl;
    cout << "Clave de la raiz: " << nodo_aux->clave << endl;
    cout << "Clave a insertar: " << laclave << endl;

    if (ArbolVacio(ar))
    {
        nodo_aux->clave = laclave;
        nodo_aux->marca = lamarca;
        nodo_aux->modelo = elmodelo;
        nodo_aux->tipo = eltipo;
        nodo_aux->potencia = lapotencia;
        return;
        //EN EL CASO DE QUE EL ARBOL ESTE VACIO SE ASIGNA LA CLAVE AL NODO RAIZ
    }

    while ((nodo_aux!=NULL) && (nodo_aux->clave!=laclave))
    {
        nodo_padre = nodo_aux; //RECORRER HASTA POSICIONARSE DONDE INSERTAR
        if( laclave < nodo_aux->clave) nodo_aux = nodo_aux->izq;
        else nodo_aux = nodo_aux->der;
    }

/* Si SE HA ENCONTRADO EL ELEMENTO, NO SE PUEDE INSERTAR */
    if (nodo_aux!=NULL)
    {
        cout << laclave << " NO SE PUEDE INSERTAR PUES YA EXISTE" << endl;
        return;
    };

    if(laclave < nodo_padre->clave)
    {
        /* SI LA CLAVE A INSERTAR ES MENOR QUE LA QUE CONTIENE EL NODO PADRE
        SE INSERTA EN EL SUBARBOL IZQUIERDO */
        struct nodoA *nodo;
        nodo = new struct nodoA;
        nodo_padre->izq = nodo;
        nodo->clave = laclave;
        nodo->marca = lamarca;
        nodo->modelo = elmodelo;
        nodo->tipo = eltipo;
        nodo->potencia = lapotencia;

        nodo->izq = nodo->der = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        /* SI LA CLAVE A INSERTAR ES MAYOR QUE LA QUE CONTIENE EL NODO PADRE
        SE INSERTA EN EL SUBARBOL DERECHO */
        struct nodoA *nodo;
        nodo = new struct nodoA;
        nodo_padre->der = nodo;
        nodo->clave = laclave;
        nodo->marca = lamarca;
        nodo->modelo = elmodelo;
        nodo->tipo = eltipo;
        nodo->potencia = lapotencia;
        nodo->izq = nodo->der = NULL;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    arbol elarbol1;
    elarbol1 = CrearArbol();

    if (ArbolVacio(elarbol1)) cout << "EL ARBOL ESTA VACIO" << endl;
    else cout << "EL ARBOL NO ESTA VACIO" << endl;

    string matricula = "1111LLL";
    string modelo= "modelo";
    string marca= "marca";
    string tipo = "tipo";
    int potencia = 500;

    string propmatricula;
    string propmodelo;
    string propmarca;
    string proptipo;
    int proppotencia;

    InsertarclaveArbol(elarbol1,"0000LLL","Marca","Modelo","T",500);
    InsertarclaveArbol(elarbol1,matricula,marca,modelo,tipo,potencia);
    InsertarclaveArbol(elarbol1,"2222LLL","Marca","Modelo","T",500);
    InsertarclaveArbol(elarbol1,"3333LLL","Marca","Modelo","T",500);
    cout << "Matricula" << endl << "Opcion: ";
    cin >> matricula;

    cout << "modelo" << endl << "Opcion: ";
    cin >> modelo;

    cout << "marca" << endl << "Opcion: ";
    cin >> marca;

    cout << "tipo" << endl << "Opcion: ";
    cin >> tipo;

    cout << "potencia" << endl << "Opcion: ";
    cin >> potencia;

    InsertarclaveArbol(elarbol1,matricula,marca,modelo,tipo,potencia);
    InsertarclaveArbol(elarbol1,"5555LLL","Marca","Modelo","T",500);
    InsertarclaveArbol(elarbol1,"6666LLL","Marca","Modelo","T",500);
    InsertarclaveArbol(elarbol1,"7777LLL","Marca","Modelo","T",500);
    InsertarclaveArbol(elarbol1,"8888LLL","Marca","Modelo","T",500);

    if (ArbolVacio(elarbol1)) cout << "EL ARBOL ESTA VACIO" << endl;
    else cout << "EL ARBOL NO ESTA VACIO" << endl;

    string num;
    cout << "Matricula a buscar: ";
    cin >> num;
    if (BusquedaclaveArbol(elarbol1->raiz,num))
    cout << "EL clave " << num << " EXISTE EN EL ARBOL" << endl;
    else
    cout << "EL clave " << num << " NO EXISTE EN EL ARBOL" << endl;

    cout << "Matricula a buscar: ";
    cin >> num;
    if (BusquedaclaveArbol(elarbol1->raiz,num))
    cout << "EL clave " << num << " EXISTE EN EL ARBOL" << endl;
    else
    cout << "EL clave " << num << " NO EXISTE EN EL ARBOL" << endl;

    cout << "desea salir?" << endl;
    int decision;
    cin >> decision;
    if(decision == 1){
        system("PAUSE");    
    }

}
```